# How to start a new blockchain/fork?

Tags: blockchain, erc-20, hardforks

I really like whats going on in the space, and have an idea of my own for a blockchain. I am aware there are ERC20 tokens - which should help me build on top of Ethereum. The concept i have in mind has a different way of dealing with transaction fee on the network rather than gas and involves microtransactions, making it impossible for me to run it on Ethereum (Which was my first choice). I am following developments on Lightning Network and Plasma for micropayments, but then Plasama isn't deployed yet.

I do not have experience building blockchains in the past, but i have been following the research going on in this space.

I really want to know what is a good place to start thinking about a new blockchain - As a ethereum fork , ERC20 or otherwise.

I have written a first draft of a whitepaper that explains my idea, and will be ready to show others very soon. What's the best way to get feedback on the paper? What are the things i need to keep in mind before getting such feedback?

Any help on these lines, deeply appreciated! :)

Comment: You can try bitcointalk.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a fork of an existing blockchain or are you writing everything from scratch?

If you're forking an existing project, you can make available a public github repository for people to review your changes.

When you're ready to share your new blockchain with the world, the [Bitcointalk Announcements Forum](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=159.0) is the most common way to gather interest for your project.

It's probably a good idea to hold some bounties for people to review the whitepaper and/or help you with various parts of the project that you might not have the correct skillsets for (e.g. graphic design or marketing).